# Java: an instance method inside a static method

Tags: java

I'm aware that we cannot call instance methods inside a static method. But, is there any way to get around it?

The following method is my static method, and score.sumall is my instance method, which prints a string nine+five+ten. I want to call this static method in the main method by System.out.println(averageScore(args)); As expected, it gives me an error. But, is there any way for me to use the string outcome nine+five+ten from the instance method, in this static method? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: `averageScore` will either need a `static` reference to the instance of `score` OR `score` will need to be passed to `averageScore` as a parameter

Comment: the static method `averageScore` does not know what `score` is. You need to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

pass the method as a parameter

```
public class score{
  public String sumall()
  {
    // do something 
    return "outcome"; // test value 
  }
}

public static String averageScore(score s, String[] args) {  
        String outcome = "":
        outcome += "average:" + s.sumall() + "/" + args.length;
        return outcome:
}
```

### Usage

```
averageScore(new score(),new String[]{"1","2"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know why I get 'invalid method declaration; return type required' error?

Comment: @studenthahahoho yea it needs a returne because we defined the method has  a returne

Comment: I do have a return, which is 'outcome'!

Comment: @studenthahahoho return "outcome" inside the method . see updated answer

Comment: @Mr.AF shouldn't your method declaration read `public static String averageScore(score s, String[] args)`? Note the missing `String` return type in your method declaration.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian yea i missed.